# I want to hold down a button for constant movement, but KEYUP is reading true even if I don't lift the key

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I want to be able to hold the key down and move my little black dot, and then release the key and have it stop.  However even if I hold the key down my if statement for key up is being executed.  Here is my code:

```
manmovemaster = 0
l = 1
f1 = 0
from random import randint
from math import sin, cos, tan, pi
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
Fps = pygame.time.Clock()
#starting variables
sw = 1200
sh = 650
r = 250
g = 250
b = 250
framerate = 40


#beginning of a man
man1x = 650
man1y = 50
mancolor=(0,0,0)
manlocation = (man1x, man1y)
Diamaterofhead = (5)
man1ymovedown = 0
man1ymoveup = False
man1xmoveright = False
man1xmoveleft = False


#game logic
while l:
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((sw,sh))
    pygame.display.set_caption("WGD THE GAME")
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((r,g,b))



    man1 = pygame.draw.circle(background,mancolor,(man1x,man1y),Diamaterofhead)
    if man1ymovedown== True:
        man1y += 1
        manmovemaster = 0

    if man1ymoveup == True:
        man1y -= 1

    if man1xmoveright == True:
        man1x +=1

    if man1xmoveleft == True:
        man1x -=1



#screen refresh

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                man1xmoveleft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                man1xmoveright = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                man1ymoveup = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                man1ymovedown = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: 
                man1xmoveleft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                man1xmoveright = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                man1ymoveup = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                man1ymovedown = False

    else:
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.get_ticks
        Fps.tick(framerate)
```

Comment: You may also want to move based on `(speed * timedelta since the last event loop)` for smooth and consistent movement.  With a static `1` your `man1` will move faster on faster frame rates and slower on slower frame rates and all frames are not created equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("WGD THE GAME")

Fps = pygame.time.Clock()

man1x = 200
man1y = 200

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255, 255, 255),(man1x,man1y), 25)

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        man1x -= 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        man1x += 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        man1y -= 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        man1y += 1

    pygame.display.flip()
    Fps.tick(60)
```

using pygame.key.get_pressed() instead of pygame.event.get() returns the state of the keys at all times, not just when you press it. So you can hold a key down and it will, and when you release it, it will stop. This will also work for diagonal movement. because it checks the state of all keys, it will check up and left so both will be true (pressed) and the character will move diagonally.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed

and then you can take all the event checking and boolean movement flags out. Also, each time through the loop you are calling pygame.init(). This isn't necessary. you also don't need to set the mode each time through the game loop, as well as the caption, and background

Comment: Am i creating another for loop? , and if so would it look like "for pressed in pygame.key.get_pressed():" ?

Comment: no, pygame.key.get_pressed() returns an array of the states of all the keys. I will update my code.

Comment: This is why this is driving me nuts, I will answer my question with the code i rewrote,  It is still only moving when I hit the key, it does not move when i hold the key down. I appreciate your help and patience.

Comment: @Christopher did you delete all the event.get() checks? If you are checking for keys in both places, the event check gets priority

Comment: @Christopher why it that else statement floating around? surrounding the flip and tick

Comment: It is just an editing error from deleting the event.get() checks.  It did not affect the program when i fixed it

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, it not moving when i hold the button down, maybe my computer is messed up.

Comment: @Christopher your computer is fine. I updated the code above to be a full cleaned up version of your code. It is tested and works

Comment: @Christopher use it as a starting point for your program. also, delete the other answer you posted as it will be confusing to other new programmers

Comment: That worked, may I asked if you know exactly what on my old code was causing the problem, or was it to messy to tell

Comment: It was a combination of checking events (not key presses) and re-initializing everything each time through the loop

Comment: @Christopher also feel free to mark my answer as correct. happy programming